# The point of discontinuity of a bijective map

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove/Disprove:The set of point of discontinuity of a bijective map from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$ is always countably infinite.

It's a standard exercise to show that any bijective function from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$ can't have finitely many discontinuity.Next,in order to find a explicit map I found that the map can be constructed so that it has countably infinite discontinuity.So, I wonder whether such map always have countably many discontinuity.

Comment: The claim as stated is false - there exist bijections $(0,1)\to[0,1]$ with uncountably infinitely many points of discontinuity. -- If the claim is merely ".. at least countably infinite", you are done once you show that it can't be done with finitely many discontinuities, and no explicit map is required (the statement would remain true even if no such bijection existed).

Comment: There are a lot of pernicious examples, there's no reason for this to be true

Comment: Maybe you want to ask whether the set of discontinuities is always infinite?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen,can you give one such example(a map with uncountably many discontinuity)?

Comment: @who it's hard to explain non-continuous maps of uncountable sets

Comment: @Don Thousand,then how can we prove that, such map exists with uncountably many discontinuity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim, as stated, is false. Consider the map $f:(0,1)\to[0,1]$ as below$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x=\frac12\\\frac1{2n}&x=\frac1{2n+2},\;n\in\mathbb N\\\frac1{2n-1}&x=\frac1{2n+1},\;n\in\mathbb N\\1-x&x\notin\mathbb Q\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Note that even if I weren't able to find such a map, the impetus lies on you to show such a map doesn't exist, not the other way around.

**Proof that the function is injective:** Consider $x,y\in(0,1)$. Note that rationals are only mapped to rationals, and irrationals only to irrationals, so we can assume that both are either rational or irrational.

If $x,y$ are irrational, and $x\neq y$, then clearly $1-x\neq1-y$. If $x,y\in\mathbb Q$, and neither is of the form $\frac1n$, then $f(x)=x$ is clearly a bijection.

If $x=\frac1n$, note that $x$ is mapped to either $1$, or another element of the form $\frac1m$. Hence, if $y$ is not of form $\frac1m$, then $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

Finally, if both $x,y$ are of the form $\frac1n$, then clearly $f(x)=f(y)\to x=y$, so the function is injective.

**Proof that the function is surjective:** Clearly, given any irrational $r$ in $[0,1]$, $1-r$ is irrational, and also in $[0,1]$. Hence, $f$ maps to all irrationals in $[0,1]$. Also, $f$ also maps to $0$ and all rationals of the form $\frac1n$. And since all rationals not of the form $\frac1n$ are mapped to themselves, all rationals not of this form are mapped to. So the function is surjective.

**Proof that the function is nowhere continuous:**

Let $x\notin\mathbb Q$. Clearly, $x\neq\frac12$. Consider a sequence of rationals $\{q_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ that converge to $x$ such that none of the rationals are of the form $\frac1n$. Clearly, $\{f(q_i)\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $x$. However, $f(x)=1-x\neq x$, which implies that the function is not continuous at irrational $x$.

Let $x\in\mathbb Q$, and let $x\neq\frac12,\frac13,\frac14$. Consider a sequence of irrationals $\{r_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ converging to $x$. Note that $\{f(r_i)\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $1-x$. But, $f(x)=x\neq1-x$, or both $x,f(x)<\frac12$, which means that $f(x)\neq1-x$. So, the function is not continuous at all rationals except $\frac12,\frac13\frac14$.

Consider $x=\frac12,\;\frac13,\text{ or }\frac14$, and consider a sequence of irrationals $\{r_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ converging to $x$. Note that $\{f(r_i)\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $\frac12,\frac23,\frac34$ respectively, which $f(x)=0,1,\frac12$ respectively. This implies that the function is not continuous at these three values.

Comment: Hmm.The map is sufficient,there were no need of explanation.Yet, the complete explanation makes it a good answer.I guessed it, but didn't try, I should.